# xmldocument add namespace prefix in same node

Tags: c#, namespaces, xmldocument

I want the output to be like this:

```
<Order xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:gml="example.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="example.com http://schemas.xyz.net/gml/2.1.2/feature.xsd"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.xyz.co.uk/xmlorders3/lig_xml_orders.xsd">
```

The code I am using  to get this is :

```
xmlDocument.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
xmlDocument.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:gml", "example.com");
xmlDocument.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
xmlDocument.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xsi:schemaLocation", "example.com http://schemas.opengis.com/gml/2.1.2/feature.xsd");     
xmlDocument.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation","http://www. xyz.co.uk/xmlorders3/lig_xml_orders.xsd");
```

But I am getting the output like this :

```
<Order xmlns:gml="example.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       schemaLocation="example.com http://schemas.xyz.net/gml/2.1.2/feature.xsd" 
       noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.xyz.co.uk/xmlorders3/lig_xml_orders.xsd">
```

Please suggest me any other way to get the required output.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

You should use another version of [SetAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ec5ak8h6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method:

```
xmlDocument.DocumentElement
    .SetAttribute("schemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "example.com http://schemas.opengis.com/gml/2.1.2/feature.xsd");
```

Answer (score -2):

i found way out. it may not be the best way. the solution is :

string xmlString = xmlDocument.InnerXml.ToString(); xmlString= xmlString.Replace("schemaLocation", "xsi:schemaLocation"); xmlString= xmlString.Replace("noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation"); xmlDocument.LoadXml(xmlString);

// now i have the xmlDocument as i required.